# Can the term "sitemap" also apply to software apps?

Tags: terminology, sitemap

A client requested us that he needed the number of pages for the app we are thinking to build.

And I came across with this curious question: is that list of pages called "sitemaps" also in a software app or a sitemap is only for websites? and if it so, how is the list of pages called in a software app? how would you call it? Said in other words, If you had to deliver to the client a list of UI pages of a software app, how would you name that document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of all pages and their hierarchy is often referred to as an [**organization structure**](http://www.usability.gov/how-to-and-tools/methods/organization-structures.html).

Comment: Say "organization structure" to me and I will be sure that you are about to present me a hierarchical arrangement of departments and functions of an organization (company). There is no way I would relate it to software functionality/screens.

Comment: Well, a list of all pages is just a list of all pages. I'm assuming he won't order them alphabetically but at the very least present them with some hierarchy. So yes, you have a point, and yes, I did make an assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Typically the reason you're showing all the screens is to illustrate how they navigate from one to the other. It's not uncommon to see "navigation overview" or "application flow" used to describe this type of diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Consider naming it:

- Interface overview
- Screen overview
- Window list

Comment: are these terms which you've seen in use, or just terms you consider to be appropriate?

Comment: These are the ones I consider appropriate as a developer and would understand as a business owner.

Answer (score 0):

I (as business owner) usually use (when talking to developers) application "screen flow" or "screen structure". It not only depicts structure and hierarchy but also the "flow" when the user use the app.